# How to build wxFormBuilder 3.x on Mac

Tags: python, wxpython, osx-mountain-lion, wxformbuilder

I downloaded [wxFormBuilder 3.4 beta mac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) to appropriate directory.

[image]

and open a terminal i run to `sh create_build_files4.sh` but console show to me following error.

```
MinSeok-ui-iMac-3:wxFormBuilder MinSeok$ sh create_build_files4.sh
create_build_files4.sh: line 7: wx-config: command not found
create_build_files4.sh: line 66: wx-config: command not found
make: *** ./premake/macosx: No such file or directory.  Stop.
create_build_files4.sh: line 91: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
create_build_files4.sh: line 92: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
create_build_files4.sh: line 93: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
create_build_files4.sh: line 95: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
```

My Environment is OS X Mountain Lion (also Mavericks). I already install `wxPython` version is 2.9.5.

What is my problem?... google, never show hint to me.

Thank in advance.

### EDIT

I'm installed wxWidgets 3.0 and placed premake4. I think It seems almost close to solving. wxFormBuilder using a lua script. but i don't know solution.lua script build code. any hint?
see a below shell create_build_files4.sh script. one thing is certain must know solution.lua script code.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Parse command line options
shared=""
arch=""
wxroot=""
wxpath=`wx-config --prefix`

# These works only on wxWidgets 2.8.10+
#wxcharset=`wx-config --query-chartype`
#wxversion=`wx-config --query-version`
for args in "$@"
do
    haveroot=`expr "${args}" : '--wx-root=.*'`
    havearch=`expr "${args}" : '--architecture=.*'`
    haverpath=`expr "${args}" : '--rpath=.*'`
    if ( [ ${args} = "--help" ] || [ ${args} = "-h" ] ); then
            echo "Available options:"
            echo
            echo "--disable-mediactrl       Disable wxMediaCtrl / wxMedia library."
            echo
            echo "--disable-shared          Use static wxWidgets build instead of shared libraries."
            echo
            echo "--disable-unicode         Whether to use an Unicode or an ANSI build."
            echo "                          Ignored in wxWidgets 2.9 and later."
            echo "                          Example: --disable-unicode produces an ANSI build."
            echo "                          Default: Unicode build on all versions."
            #       echo "                          Current: $wxcharset"
            echo
            echo "--wx-root                 Specify the wxWidgets build path,"
            echo "                          useful for wxWidgets builds not installed"
            echo "                          in your system (alternate/custom builds)"
            echo "                          Example: --wx-root=/home/devel/wx/3.0/buildgtk"
            echo "                          Current: $wxpath"
            echo
            echo "--architecture            Specify build architecture (e.g. --architecture=i386)."
            echo "--rpath                   Specify a rpath  (e.g. --rpath=/usr/lib/wxformbuilder)."
            echo
            exit
    elif [ ${args} = "--disable-mediactrl" ]; then
        mediactrl="--disable-mediactrl"
        continue
    elif [ ${args} = "--disable-unicode" ]; then
        wxunicode="--disable-unicode"
        continue
    elif [ ${args} = "--disable-shared" ]; then
        shared="--disable-shared"
        continue
    elif [ ${args} = "--disable-unicode" ]; then
        wxunicode="--disable-unicode"
        continue
    elif ( [ "$haveroot" -gt "0" ] ); then
        wxroot=${args}
        continue
    elif ( [ "$havearch" -gt "0" ] ); then
        arch=${args}
        continue
    elif ( [ "$haverpath" -gt "0" ] ); then
        rpath=${args}
        continue
    fi
done

# Autodetect wxWidgets version
if [ "$wxroot" = "" ]; then
    wxver=`wx-config --release`
else
    wxpath=${wxroot#-*=}
    wxver=`$wxpath/wx-config --release`
fi

wxversion="--wx-version="$wxver

# Autodetect OS
isbsd=`expr "$unamestr" : '.*BSD'`
platform="unknown"
unamestr=$(uname)

if ( [ "$isbsd" -gt "0" ] ); then
    platform="bsd"
elif [ "$unamestr" = "Linux" ]; then
    platform="linux"
elif [ "$unamestr" = "Darwin" ]; then
    platform="macosx"
fi

# Build premake
cd build
make CONFIG=Release -C./premake/$platform

./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch codeblocks
./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch $rpath codelite
./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch $rpath gmake
if [ "$platform" = "macosx" ]; then
   ./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch xcode3
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @melto, a stable released version, 3.1.70, for os x works as well. The link to sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/files/wxformbuilder/3.1.70/wxFormBuilder-3.1.dmg/download

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use the stable release: **wxFormBuilder-3.1** 
This is available as dmg on Sourceforge. I assume the previuous steps are not necessary for this package.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have **wx-config** installed on your machine. This is included in **wxWidgets** (FAQ Mac: http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/faqmac.htm#macplat). You need to keep in mind, that you need to have Xcode installed to continue. Building the package will take some time.

- get wxWidgets (i.e. v. 3.0.0 http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads)
- unzip the tar.bz2 and build it:

  tar -xfvj wxWidgets-3.0.0.tar.bz2

  cd wxWidgets-3.0.0

  ./configure

  make

  sudo make install
- try to run the shell skript again

Comment: Thank! but, my question modifed. check please :)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Was able to install wxWidgets fine, still the same error as the OP when trying to install wxFormBuilder after. No better off.